# How to kill all python processes except one from bash

Tags: bash

How can I kill from bash all python processes excluding one python script. 
(I know its name, but its pid can be changed sometimes).

I need kind of `pkill -f "python"` but with excluding the python specific script.

Please advise.

Answer (score 15):

`ps aux |grep python |grep -v 'pattern_of_process_you_dont_want_to_kill' |awk '{print $2}' |xargs kill`

Update: step-by-step explanation as requested in comments

- `ps aux |grep python` - show all processes which are matching `python` pattern
- `grep -v 'pattern_of_process_you_dont_want_to_kill'` - exclude process you don't want to kill
- `awk '{print $2}'` - show second field of output, it is PID.
- `xargs kill` - apply `kill` command to each input arg (PID).

If you are not familiar with `xargs` command, i'd advise you to do not worry if you do not understand it right away. It could appear quite tricky  for the first time. I posted very simple example of its usage, you may google for more.

Comment: Great, but can you please explain how does it work, For example what is awk '{print$2}' and xargs kill?

Comment: `awk '{print $2}' ` - prints second field of `ps` output, in current case it is `PID`. `xargs` applies `kill` command to each `PID`

Comment: Putting that in a comment is nice, but I'd rather vote for your answer after that well-formatted comment was integrated into your answer.